# Pagespeed - Defer loading of slideshow images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am trying to reduce my pagespeed and the slideshow I have is my main hurdle.  For simplicity I only show using 3 images in my code below...I actual have 17 rather large images.  What I am trying to figure out is how to load the first image as an img src or base64 and defer the remaining images until load has completed.

html of the slide show (uses jquery and js called loopedslider1) loopedSlider js can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/tS27H/

```
<div id="slider">
<div id="loopedSlider1">
    <div class="container1">
        <div class="slides1">
            <div>
                <img src="i/1.jpg" width="624" height="535" alt="">
                    <p>Copyright © 2014 - All Rights Reserved.</p></div>
            <div>
                <img src="i/2.jpg" width="624" height="535" alt="">
                    <p>Copyright © 2014 - All Rights Reserved.</p></div>
            <div>
                <img src="i/3.jpg" width="624" height="535" alt="">
                    <p>Copyright © 2014 - All Rights Reserved.</p></div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id=slider1-button-wrap>
            <a class="previous slider1-button-left" href="#">Left</a>
            <a class="next slider1-button-right" href="#">Right</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I looked at doing a sprite, base64, sprite of a base64, defer images in css using:

```
<script>
 function downloadAtOnload1() {
 var element1 = document.createElement("style");
 element1.src = "xd.css";
 document.body.appendChild(element1);
 }  
 if (window.addEventListener)
 window.addEventListener("load", downloadAtOnload1, false);
 else if (window.attachEvent)
 window.attachEvent("onload", downloadAtOnload1);
 else window.onload = downloadAtOnload1;
</script>

<div id="image2">
    <p>Copyright © 2014 - All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>

 #image2{background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,longstring}
```

I can get the slide show to run only when using the html img src.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about this as a flow? 1. Load whatever the users will see above the fold. 2. After `window.load`, load the rest of the images. 3. When all of the images have loaded, start your slideshow.

Comment: I don't know if this is of any help but the <img> element does have an onload event that you could investigate using.

Comment: What browsers do you want to support?

Comment: Also could you get your fiddle actually working?

Comment: @Jasper I understand what you are saying...the slideshow is above the fold with enough delay that if I could figure out how to defer the rest of the images if should work.

Comment: @jeff I will take a look at your suggestion.

Comment: @cgatian...as many browsers as I can.  Chrome, Safari, IE if possible.  I attempted 3x's to get the fiddle working and all I get is a blank black screen.

Answer (score 0):

ok...so here is how I solved this

Create a very small 1px by 1px image I called blank.png

Change my HTML to this

```
<div id="slider">
<div id="loopedSlider1">
    <div class="container1">
        <div class="slides1">
            <div>
                <img src="i/1.jpg" width="624" height="535" alt="">
                    <p>Copyright © 2014 - All Rights Reserved.</p></div>
            <div>
                <img id="i2" src="blank.png" width="624" height="535" alt="">
                    <p>Copyright © 2014 - All Rights Reserved.</p></div>
            <div>
                <img id="i3" src="blank.png" width="624" height="535" alt="">
                    <p>Copyright © 2014 - All Rights Reserved.</p></div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id=slider1-button-wrap>
            <a class="previous slider1-button-left" href="#">Left</a>
            <a class="next slider1-button-right" href="#">Right</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

by leaving the first image in the slide show, which is one of the true images I want to show, the delay in the slide show allows for all the blank.png images to be replace using a deferred javascript.

My defer js script tag placed at the very bottom of the html tag just before closing body tag

```
<script>
 // Add a script element as a child of the body
  function downloadJSAtOnload() {
 var element = document.createElement("script");
 element.src = "x.js";
 document.body.appendChild(element);
 }
 // Check for browser support of event handling capability
 if (window.addEventListener)
 window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
 else if (window.attachEvent)
 window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
 else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

What I put in my x.js file

```
jQuery(function(){
$('#i2').attr('src','i/2.jpg')
$('#i3').attr('src','i/3.jpg')
});
```

Comment: If if run my page through for page speed.... i/1.jpg and blank.png are  the only images that count against my page speed...the rest are deferred until after the page is loaded. You could potentially reduce this down to even 1 by making the blank.png a base64 image.